# highchart color as classname inside data series doesn't apply to legend

Tags: charts, highcharts

Hello! I have problem with color in highchart library. I define class name of color inside data series. Class apply only to pie path but does not apply for legend. Ноw define color as class inside data series for all elements inside chart

```js
Highcharts.chart('lvl-chart', {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
             legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        layout: 'vertical',
        x: 0,
        y: 100
    },
            plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
             series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    data: [{
      name: 'Chrome',
      className:'emergency',
      y: 61.41,
    }, {
      name: 'Internet Explorer',
      className:'emergency',
      y: 11.84
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      className:'emergency',
      y: 10.85
    }, {
      name: 'Edge',
      className:'emergency',
      y: 4.67
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      className:'emergency',
      y: 4.18
    }, {
      name: 'Other',
      className:'emergency',
      y: 7.05,
    }]
  }]
        });
```

```css
.emergency{
  background-color: #FF6347;
  fill: #FF6347;
}
```

```html
<div id="lvl-chart" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use the className? You should be able to achieve it by defining the `plotOptions.pie.colors` array.

```
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true,
            colors: ['#FF6347']
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/463czorb/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.colors

---

EDIT

To update the legend items colors to the same as the point has assigned via CSS you need to enable the `styledMode` in the chart.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f7wpbax3/

API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Yes, i need use ClassName in data. Class Name matches with name of data series. I receive data series from ajax jquery. if i define color instead of class all work good. But if i define classname legend color icon is different from part pie Example data:

`{name: 'Emergency',
      className:'emergency',
      y: 11.84},
{name: 'Alert',
      className:'alert',
      y: 11.84},
{name: 'Warning',
      className:'warning',
      y: 11.84}`

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the repeated question, could you please suggest how to pass the name of the class to the tooltip. I've tried many options, but none of them work.

Comment: @user389128 you can use the tooltip formatter callback to display whatever you want in the tooltip. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mptwdovf/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter